# I build a levelping function. My problem is that the embedded message doesnt mention the person. How do I solve this problem?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am building a level function for my discord.py bot. If the person reaches the next level the bot sends a message in a channel. I learned u can ping someone by using <@memberid>. This doesnt work in my case. This is my function:

```
async def new_level_ping(bot, memberid, guildid, xpbefore, xpadded): #called every time a member get xp
    oldlevel = math.floor((xpbefore ** 0.5) / 5)
    newlevel = math.floor(((xpbefore + xpadded) ** 0.5) / 5)
    if oldlevel != newlevel:
        mentionedmember = "<@" + str(memberid) +">"
        filename = "./database/database.db"
        connection = sqlite3.connect(filename) #connect to polldatabase
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT levelingsystemstatus FROM guildsetup WHERE guildid = ?", (guildid,))
        levelingsystemstatus = next(cursor, [None])[0]
        if levelingsystemstatus == True:
            cursor.execute("SELECT levelingpingmessagechannel FROM guildsetup WHERE guildid = ?", (guildid,))
            channelid = next(cursor, [None])[0]
            channel = await bot.fetch_channel(channelid)
            #connection.commit()
            connection.close()
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f'Congratulations {mentionedmember}', description=f'You reached level {newlevel}', color=discord.Color.green())
            await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

How do I solve this problem?

The whole problem is that it doesnt mention the person(look at the picture)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mentioning members inside of an embed is impossible, you could try to change the send line to `await channel.send(mentionedmember, embed=embed)`.